# Laravel: Executing query before firing off email

Tags: php, laravel

I am using a query and chunking the records 10 at a time.
Following the query, I am taking $totalOrders and doing something with it.  I want to ensure that the email call is sent only once though.  Am I using this correctly to ensure that all, regardless of how many Orders there are, are ran through `->checkStatus` before I get to the bottom block that sends off my email?

```
protected function fillOrders()
{
    $totalOrders = [];


    Order::where('order_status', '!=', Order::FILL)
        ->limit(3000)
        ->chunk(10, function ($orders) use (&$totalOrders) {
            $totalOrders = array_merge($totalOrders, $this->checkStatus($orders));
        });

    if (count($totalOrders) > 0) {
        d("How many times does this get fired??");
        (new Mailer)->sendOrdersEmail($totalOrders);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you see any benefit of using chunk here? can't you just use with() to get status along with the current data set? limit 3000 is a safe limit, you can check your memory usage using both methods. And yes, in both conditions, you mail should go once only as per current code.

Comment: @Manpreet thanks! `$this->checkStatus($orders)` calls USPS's api, which can only handle checking 10 orders at one time, so I have to process them 10 at a time for this

Comment: @Manpreet actually, it looks like `$totalOrders = array_merge($totalOrders, $this->checkStatus($orders));` is run even if the query returns nothing.  Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: chunk(10, function ($orders) use (&$totalOrders) {
            if(count($orders)) { $totalOrders = array_merge($totalOrders, $this->checkStatus($orders)); }
        })

Comment: but I reckon it must not run if there are no orders, even without explicitly checking for count

Comment: ah you're right, it doesn't run if there are no order regardless of explicitly checking for count -- thank you